# Contact time for sanitizing bottles with diversol

Tags: sanitation, bottles

To sanitize bottles with diversol can I simply put the solution in a vinator, pump it into the bottle a couple of times and rinse?

Or does it require to soak in the bottles for 20 minutes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't find a definitive source from a manufacturer, but everything I'm seeing from third parties suggests you need a solid 20 minutes of contact. If you don't mind me asking, why use this sanitizer? It sounds like a lot of hassle (long contact time, corrosive of stainless, needs rinsing, contains bleach, etc.)

Comment: It came with my kit and all I have at the moment. I'll probably get something easier for next time.

Comment: Sounds good. Make sure you rinse really, really well (unless, of course, you like a subtle note of bandaid in your beer).

Comment: @MalFet: With the right marketing, that could do well: "Band-aid brew: Makes everything all right!"